# Add /sbin to $PATH but just temporary

Tags: unix, shell, path, sudo

There are many answers about how to add a directory to $PATH.  However, I am looking for a way to add it to a path temporarily.

For example, when running a script as sudo, not all scripts have the full directory path, and I would like to add it for one instance, so that the script can run.

Comment: A wrapper script that adds the directory to path, runs the script you want, and then removes the directory from path would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to this is to include paths in the script commands.  So rather than

```
ip addr
```

You would instead have

```
/sbin/ip addr
```

This removes the reliance on the path having the right entries.  You can update the path variable in a the script, and it will only exist for the script and any child processes, and revert once they terminate.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

This adds `/sbin` to the existing path.

Answer (score 0):

The `env` command does exactly what you want:

```
env variable=value command
```

For the duration of `command`, `$variable` is set to `value`, but the current shell environment is unaffected, and is retained on subsequent commands.

In your case you would want something like:

```
env PATH=/sbin:$PATH command
```

Note that `env` is an external command, so unexported variables and aliases are not accessible while `command` is running.